# React Native ListView taking 100% height

Tags: react-native-ios

[image]

My ListView container is taking 100% height even when their are less content in the list.

**My Code :**

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, width: '95%', flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignSelf: 'center' }}>
  <Card style={{ width: '95%', alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: 10 }}>
   <ListView
     dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
     renderRow={(item) =>
           <CardItem
              key={`transaction-${item.data.transactionid}`}
           >
                 // my list code was here
           </CardItem>}
     ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
     onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
     refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
     onEndReached={this.fetchGoalTransactions}
     onEndReachedThreshold={50}
    />
 </Card>
```

Comment: try adding `flex: 1` to either your `Card` component style or create a style for your `ListView` and pop it in there

Answer (score 0):

```
<View style={{flex:1}}>
 <View style={{flex:2}}>
    //Here is your List View
</View>
<View style={{flex:2}}>
//Its a Empty View
</View>
</View>
```

In order to bound the height of a ListView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height,because Lisview uses Scrollview

From [ScrollView docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html)

Comment: thank you for answering. But implementing above suggestion will restrict the card component height. Now If I have more data in list the card component height will remain same. for ex(50%). So I need to the list view to take height according to the data in the list view.